# PST/PDT in DateTime.parse in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, datetime, timezone

I want to be able to parse a date string which might be in PST or PDT
according to daylight savings. This means that half a year the date will
be PST and the other half the date will be PDT.

This is my code now:

`DateTime.parse('2016-02-21 10:00:02 PST/PDT')`

This will only parse the date as PST (GMT-8).

How can I parse a date+time in PST/PDT automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just a note:

DateTime.parse('2016-02-21 10:00:02 PST/PDT') will always parse to PST (Standard Time), just like DateTime.parse('2016-02-21 10:00:02 PDT') will always parse to PDT (Daylight time). This is because DateTime & Time libraries are expecting that the timezone is explicit, rather than 'PST/PDT' which is saying 'I could be x or y'. If it was smarter it could work out that both of these where in the same zone and that they were daylight savings equivalents, but sadly not at this moment.

A few options:
1) Use a timezone gem to translate the time into local zones
2) Manually put in PST or PDT depending on year

I tend to store all date/times in UTC and translate as I need them.

I use the [TZInfo gem](https://tzinfo.github.io/) to display/calculate based on local time. It uses timezones from [here](http://www.iana.org/time-zones)

```
recorded_time = Time.now.getutc

tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get('US/Pacific')
local_created_at = tz.utc_to_local(recorded_time)
```

Now this will not solve your issue if you have data already stored in DateTime already or if your inbound data is already marked up this way. If it is, I would suggest you parse it based on date. You can create a look up table using this data: http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/los-angeles

EDIT: Just realised the TZinfo is able to solve this for you:

```
tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get('US/Pacific')
=> #<TZInfo::DataTimezone: US/Pacific>

tz.local_to_utc(Time.parse('2016-07-21 10:00:02 PST/PDT')) 
=> 2016-07-21 17:00:02 UTC

tz.local_to_utc(Time.parse('2016-02-21 10:00:02 PST/PDT'))
=> 2016-02-21 18:00:02 UTC
```